# Difference in reported p-values between lm and aov in R

Tags: r, regression, anova, linear-model, sums-of-squares

What explains the differences in p-values in the following `aov` and `lm` calls ?
Is the difference only due to different types of sums-of-squares calculations ?

```
set.seed(10)
data=rnorm(12)
f1=rep(c(1,2),6)
f2=c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6))
summary(aov(data~f1*f2))
summary(lm(data~f1*f2))$coeff
```

Answer (score 17):

`summary(aov)` uses so called Type I (sequential) sums of squares. `summary(lm)` uses so called Type III sums of squares, which is not sequential. See [gung's answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20455/1909) for details.

---

Note that you need to call `lm(data ~ factor(f1) * factor(2))` (`aov()`automatically converts the RHS of the formula to factors). Then note the denominator for the general $t$-statistic in linear regression (see this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16956) for further explanations):

$$t = \frac{\hat{\psi} - \psi_{0}}{\hat{\sigma} \sqrt{\bf{c}' (\bf{X}'\bf{X})^{-1} \bf{c}}}$$

$\bf{c}' (\bf{X}'\bf{X})^{-1} \bf{c} $ differs for each tested $\beta$ coefficient because the vector $\bf{c}$ changes. In contrast, the denominator in the ANOVA $F$-test is always MSE.

Comment: I think the first sentence of this answer is wrong. The difference seems to be *precisely* due to different types of sum of squares: namely, type I vs. type II/III. Type I is sequential, which is what `lm` reports, whereas Type II/III is not. This is explained in quite some detail in @gung's answer that you linked to.

Comment: @amoeba What do you suggest to correct the answer?

Comment: I edited the first paragraph, see if you are okay with the edit, and feel free to change it as you like.

Answer (score 4):

```
set.seed(10)
data=rnorm(12)
f1=rep(c(1,2),6)
f2=c(rep(1,6),rep(2,6))
summary(aov(data~f1*f2))
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
f1           1  0.535  0.5347   0.597  0.462
f2           1  0.002  0.0018   0.002  0.966
f1:f2        1  0.121  0.1208   0.135  0.723
Residuals    8  7.169  0.8962               
summary(lm(data~f1*f2))$coeff
               Estimate Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.05222024   2.732756  0.0191090 0.9852221
f1          -0.17992329   1.728346 -0.1041014 0.9196514
f2          -0.62637109   1.728346 -0.3624106 0.7264325
f1:f2        0.40139439   1.093102  0.3672066 0.7229887
```

These are two different codes. from the Lm model you need the coefficients. while from the aov model you are just tabulating the sources of variation. Try the code

```
anova(lm(data~f1*f2))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: data
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
f1         1 0.5347 0.53468  0.5966 0.4621
f2         1 0.0018 0.00177  0.0020 0.9657
f1:f2      1 0.1208 0.12084  0.1348 0.7230
Residuals  8 7.1692 0.89615
```

This gives the tabulation of the sources of variation leading to the same results.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question, which asks why the p-values for `f1` and `f2` differ in the two summaries of your top panel.  It looks like you are only showing that `summary(aov(...))` and `anova(lm(...))` in `R` have similar output.